# Comparing value of activerecord column with string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

hie,

I have one model as Area where i have column as "Location" having one word of specific area

Now i want to compare this location with params which may contain more that one words.

e.g

Value of location column is "Kerala" and my params value is "Malappuram, Kerala, India"

So now how can i fire a query in Rails??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
params = "Malappuram, Kerala, India"
Area.where(:location => params.split(',')) # params.split(',') = ["Malappuram", "Kerala", "India"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `include?`

```
params[:location].include? location
```

[Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-include-3F)